# Are there any plans for Linux to add higher-level things like Windows' WaitForMultipleObjects?

Tags: ipc, flock

WaitForMultipleObjects is one of several Windows kernel functions that can suspend and synchronize a calling thread with other threads until resources or etc are available, similar to flock in Linux, but handles everything but file locking.

WaitForMultipleObjects supports an array of events (can be a mixture of change notifications, console input, events, memory notifications, mutexes, processes, semaphores, threads, and timers), a timeout or polling option, and an AND/OR option and reports which fired first, and it can be used independently by multiple threads at once without knowledge of each other.

(I was looking for an IPC lock with timeout and things like using SIGALRM with flock where suggested which I can't risk using because SIGALRM might be in use in other multi-threaded libraries I don't have source to. I settled on using polling with LOCK_NB and tiny sleeps, and I am pretty sure I am not losing any "fair lock" benefits.)

Comment: From context, I am guessing you are referring to kernel calls or something similar that would be used in the context of writing a piece of software and not about something a regular user of the OS would use, is that right? Please [edit] your question and clarify that, bearing in mind that most of us here have no knowledge of Windows so we have no idea if this `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a library, a kernel call, a graphical program or what.

Comment: I don't know what `WaitForMultipleObjects` is specifically, but that sounds similar to `select` or `poll`.

Comment: I added a brief summary of WaitForMultipleObjects in description.
Select and poll might be alternatives although I've only seen their use with sockets.
I have since seen System V might have more but little used cross-process synchronization mechanisms, but I don't know anything about that.
In my case, I needed to control access to shared hardware, and flock with a dummy file seemed the only choice, and adding a failsafe timeout seemed problematic. Windows has nice synchronization objects and functions that seem more appropriate than dummy files.

Comment: Maybe ask a concrete question: What are you trying to do, and what was the outcome?

Comment: Boost libraries for Linux might provide better synchronization objects but I suspect they are layered on top of other kernel functions not designed for those purposes.
Use of select might be a possibility but it seems not designed (or named) for general synchronization.
I look and find things like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651857/how-to-wait-effectively-on-a-set-of-semaphore
System D is one effort to update Linux I am aware of; I was wondering of there are others attempting to directly support higher-level scalable kernel functions - for complex synchronization in this case.

Comment: Aside from trying to learn Linux more, I was trying to control multiple processes and threads sharing the same hardware ADC converter many times a second with efficient locking. I found flock, but could not find a timeout option; SIGALRM was mentioned for forcing timeouts, but it is per process.

Comment: Linux has synchronization primitives, they don't get coupled with other types of events. What are you trying to do? What is the expected outcome?  Would a condition variable solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you Andy & etc. Specifically, I am looking for a cross- process lock with sub-second timeout support and release on program exit/crash so multiple C/C++ & Python programs can share a common hardware ADC and interleave their processing. The best I found was flock for a file in ram could be polled with 3 mSec sleeps using around 1% Cpu if waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there seems to the [Futex2](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.16-sys_futex_waitv) work that should aim providing a low level interface that will allow to implement an equivalent to `WaitForMultipleObjects` in the linux kernel.